# When react timer component is not called, but affect on all other open component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I write a component to get verify number with 2 minutes timer in a component, but when this component is not called, this runs in the background and reload index in 2 minutes.

```
class RegisterCode_Modal extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

       this.state={
         secondsRemaining: 59,
         minutesRemaining: 1
       };
      this.tick=this.tick.bind(this);
      this.closeThisModal=this.closeThisModal.bind(this);
    }

    tick() {

     if(this.state.secondsRemaining > 0 && this.state.minutesRemaining > 0){
      this.setState({secondsRemaining: (this.state.secondsRemaining - 1)});
     }
     else if(this.state.secondsRemaining > 0 && this.state.minutesRemaining == 0){
      this.setState({secondsRemaining: (this.state.secondsRemaining - 1)});
        if(this.state.minutesRemaining==0 && this.state.secondsRemaining==0){
            this.closeThisModal();
          }
     }
      else if (this.state.secondsRemaining <= 0 && this.state.minutesRemaining==0) {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
      else if(this.state.secondsRemaining==0 && this.state.minutesRemaining==1){
        this.setState({minutesRemaining: (this.state.minutesRemaining-1)});
        this.setState({secondsRemaining: 59});
      }

    }
    closeThisModal(){
      window.location.reload();
    }
    componentDidMount() {

      this.setState({ secondsRemaining: this.state.secondsRemaining });
      this.setState({ minutesRemaining: this.state.minutesRemaining });
      this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
```

Code in above is component for timer.how do I solve background run of this component?

Comment: Can you please show where the RegisterCode_Modal is called? It's likely you need to add a condition there to keep it from instantiating (e.g. `isCodeUnregistered && <RegisterCode_Modal />`)

Comment: Yes, I soled it.... thanks a lot.....